# C# Generic dictionary function

Tags: c#, generics, dictionary, casting

Hi I would like to create a dynamic generic input box function which  allows the user to select an input from  a list of inputs and then return this. For the list of Items I want to use a dictionary.

For the declaration I was thinking along the lines of the following:

```
public static DialogResult InputBox<KeyType, ValueType>(string aTitle, string aPromptText, Dictionary<KeyType, ValueType> aDictionary, ref  KeyValuePair<KeyType, ValueType> aReturnPair)
```

I already have two similar functions, one for dates and one for strings.

But I want to know is the dictionary one possible?
How do I handle the casting? Do I have to pass the type of the key and value as well or can I retrieve this during run time?

Also is it possible to specify the "function" to use to retrieve the name to use for display For example I have the following struct:

```
public struct Person
{
   public int Age;
   public string Name;
   public string Surname;
}
```

How can I tell the function to use Person.Surname for display purposes?

Example usage:

```
Dictionary<int, Person> Persons = new Dictionary<int,Person>();
KeyValuePair<int, Person> lPair= new KeyValuePair<int,Person> 
DialogResult dialogResult = DialogResult.Cancel
While (dialogResult == DialogResult.Cancel)
{
    dialogResult = CustomForm.InputBox<int, Person>("title", "prompt", Persons, ref lPair, Person.Surname);
}
```

String input function

```
public static DialogResult InputBox(string aTitle, string aPromptText, ref string aValue, Boolean aPassword = false )
    {
        Form lForm = new Form();
        Label lLabel = new Label();
        TextBox lTextBox = new TextBox();
        Button lButtonOk = new Button();
        Button lButtonCancel = new Button();

        lForm.Text = aTitle;
        lLabel.Text = aPromptText;
        lTextBox.Text = aValue;

        if (aPassword)
        {
            lTextBox.PasswordChar = '*';
        }
        lButtonOk.Text = "OK";
        lButtonCancel.Text = "Cancel";
        lButtonOk.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
        lButtonCancel.DialogResult = DialogResult.Cancel;

        lLabel.SetBounds(9, 20, 372, 13);
        lTextBox.SetBounds(12, 36, 372, 20);
        lButtonOk.SetBounds(228, 72, 75, 23);
        lButtonCancel.SetBounds(309, 72, 75, 23);

        lLabel.AutoSize = true;
        lTextBox.Anchor = lTextBox.Anchor | AnchorStyles.Right;
        lButtonOk.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Bottom | AnchorStyles.Right;
        lButtonCancel.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Bottom | AnchorStyles.Right;

        lForm.ClientSize = new Size(396, 107);
        lForm.Controls.AddRange(new Control[] { lLabel, lTextBox, lButtonOk, lButtonCancel });
        lForm.ClientSize = new Size(Math.Max(300, lLabel.Right + 10), lForm.ClientSize.Height);
        lForm.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedDialog;
        lForm.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
        lForm.MinimizeBox = false;
        lForm.MaximizeBox = false;
        lForm.AcceptButton = lButtonOk;
        lForm.CancelButton = lButtonCancel;

        DialogResult dialogResult = lForm.ShowDialog();
        aValue = lTextBox.Text;
        return dialogResult;
    }
```

Comment: Where do you need to use the dictionary?

Comment: The idea is to have an override of the string function, just for dictionary.  I want to be able to give the function a dictionary and then it will prompt the user for a section.  It is for a library I am creating for use in all our applications. Thats why I want the key and value dynamic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to create one Here is the completed function

```
public static DialogResult InputBox<KeyType, ValueType>(string aTitle, string aPromptText, Dictionary<KeyType, ValueType> aDictionary, ref  KeyValuePair<KeyType, ValueType> aReturnPair, Func<ValueType, string> aDelegate)
    {
        Form lForm = new Form();
        Label lLabel = new Label();
        ComboBox lComboBox = new ComboBox();
        Button lButtonOk = new Button();
        Button lButtonCancel = new Button();

        lForm.Text = aTitle;
        lLabel.Text = aPromptText;
        foreach (KeyValuePair<KeyType, ValueType> lPair in aDictionary)
        {
            lComboBox.Items.Add(aDelegate(lPair.Value));
        }


        lButtonOk.Text = "OK";
        lButtonCancel.Text = "Cancel";
        lButtonOk.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
        lButtonCancel.DialogResult = DialogResult.Cancel;

        lLabel.SetBounds(9, 20, 372, 13);
        lComboBox.SetBounds(12, 36, 372, 20);
        lButtonOk.SetBounds(228, 72, 75, 23);
        lButtonCancel.SetBounds(309, 72, 75, 23);

        lLabel.AutoSize = true;
        lComboBox.Anchor = lComboBox.Anchor | AnchorStyles.Right;
        lButtonOk.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Bottom | AnchorStyles.Right;
        lButtonCancel.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Bottom | AnchorStyles.Right;

        lForm.ClientSize = new Size(396, 107);
        lForm.Controls.AddRange(new Control[] { lLabel, lComboBox, lButtonOk, lButtonCancel });
        lForm.ClientSize = new Size(Math.Max(300, lLabel.Right + 10), lForm.ClientSize.Height);
        lForm.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedDialog;
        lForm.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
        lForm.MinimizeBox = false;
        lForm.MaximizeBox = false;
        lForm.AcceptButton = lButtonOk;
        lForm.CancelButton = lButtonCancel;

        DialogResult dialogResult = lForm.ShowDialog();
        if ((dialogResult == DialogResult.OK) && (lComboBox.SelectedIndex > -1) && (lComboBox.SelectedIndex < aDictionary.Count))
        {
            foreach (KeyValuePair<KeyType, ValueType> lPair in aDictionary)
            {
                if (string.Compare(aDelegate(lPair.Value),lComboBox.Items[lComboBox.SelectedIndex].ToString())== 0)
                {
                    aReturnPair = lPair;
                }
            }

        }            
        return dialogResult;
    }
```

You call it as follows:

```
DialogResult dialogResult = CustomForm.InputBox<int, Person>("title", "prompt", Persons, ref lPair,  (Person) => Person.Name);
```

Comment: Yes something like this you need to use Func to solve it, please if you find my answer correct mark it as an answer :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use delegates function that take a dictionary as parameter and return a string to the user, something like this:

```
Func<Dictionary<Object, Object>,string> userOutput
```

By adding this parameter to the function you can write the logic of casting and how you want to prompt the output to the user, you call it like this:

```
txtTextBox.Text = userOutput(dictionary);
```

Comment: I dont get what you mean. I want to the same with that my string input function does. I have attached it to the main post.

Comment: mmm I see now what you mean thanks. But how would I make the declaration if I want to call it as follows: Person.Surname   This is with the example in the original post.

Comment: I have added an example how I want to use it